# Querying Results from End of the table

Tags: sql, mysql

Normal behavior of the SQL Table is to add new rows in end of the table. I want to query results of single row only.

So mysql command is

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE country='india' LIMIT 1
```

this will give me the first entry with the country india. But i want to get the last person so i used order by DESC

```
SELECT id FROM users ORDER BY DESC WHERE country='india' LIMIT 1
```

This gives me the desired result but i wanted to know if its the pefect way to achieve it.

What Order actually does?
Does it fetch the result and then order it by Descending or Does it query from the end of the table?

Comment: Ordinary tables do not have an order. There is no "start" or "end", they're just bags of rows.

Comment: I would guess the answer is that it can skip sorting everything iff you have an index on the country column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making some assumptions that aren't correct.

Mysql doesn't store the rows at the end of table: rows are stored where there's space. It can be at the end, but can also be in the middle, if routes were deleted. And retrieves in an order that may appear ordered.

In your first query you're retrieving without ordering the results, and you may have surprises. Like when an index used on another column, and the first result found doesn't have the highest Id.

About limiting the results, the "limit" clause doesn't provides means to give you "the last N results". Only "the first N" or the "skip the first M and give me the following N".

So, the answer to your question is that you need to provide an "order by" clause so that you the data in the order that you need.

And, to retrieve the highest Id you must order descending and add "limit 1", as you did.

Your query isn't correct, because you need to order by a column. This is correct:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE country='india' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```